# Problem in awk command

Tags: awk, csh

I have to extract latitude and longitude from an ASCII text file in Ubuntu using the `awk` command. I wrote the code below and saved it in `untitled.sh`:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set file =  $1
if($1! = "") then
awk'{ \
if(NR == 1) NCOLS = $2; \
if(NR == 2) NROWS = $2; \
if(NR == 3) LL_LNG = $2; \
if(NR == 4) LL_LAT = $2; \
if(NR == 5) CELLSIZE = $2; \
if(NR == 6) NODATA = $2; \
if(NR > 6) { \
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { \
  if( $i!= NODATA ) { \
    printf( "%f %f %f\n", LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE + CELLSIZE / 2, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) *    CELLSIZE - CELLSIZE / 2, $i ) \
#printf( "%f %f %f\n" LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) * CELLSIZE, $i ) \
     } \
   } \
  } \
 } '$file
```

After that I run it by `csh untitled.sh` or `csh csh.sh test.txt`, but it is telling:

```
 if: Expression Syntax.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: The error message comes from `csh` rather than `awk` I think (your if(`$1! = "")` needs to be `if($1 != "")`, and there needs to be a corresponding `endif`). Why are you even using `csh`?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax issue, you  need `endif` for your if `if($1! = "") then` + this if statement should be `if ($1 != "") then`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two major issues here. First, you are using csh for scripting. That is a very bad idea. I suggest you read Tom Christiansen's great essay [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) to understand why this should be avoided. Csh is fine as a shell, but really shouldn't be used for scripting.

Now, the reason this isn't working is the syntax error. You need `!=` and not `! =`. Strictly speaking, you also need an `endif` but the script will work without it since there are no operations outside the `if` block. It will break if you try to do anything else though, so you really should have it.

Also, your script will break if you try to run it on a file whose name contains spaces because [you're not quoting your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222). With all this in mind, here's a working version of your script:

```sh
#!/bin/csh -f
set file =  "$1"
if("$file" != "") then
awk '{ \
if(NR == 1) NCOLS = $2; \
if(NR == 2) NROWS = $2; \
if(NR == 3) LL_LNG = $2; \
if(NR == 4) LL_LAT = $2; \
if(NR == 5) CELLSIZE = $2; \
if(NR == 6) NODATA = $2; \
if(NR > 6) { \
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { \
  if( $i!= NODATA ) { \
    printf( "%f %f %f\n", LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE + CELLSIZE / 2, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) *    CELLSIZE - CELLSIZE / 2, $i ) \
#printf( "%f %f %f\n" LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) * CELLSIZE, $i ) \
     } \
   } \
  } \
 } ' "$file"
endif
```

Of course, if this is all you want to do, you could make your life easier and just use `awk` directly instead of fiddling around with `csh`:

```C
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ 
    if(NR == 1) NCOLS = $2; 
    if(NR == 2) NROWS = $2; 
    if(NR == 3) LL_LNG = $2;
    if(NR == 4) LL_LAT = $2;
    if(NR == 5) CELLSIZE = $2; 
    if(NR == 6) NODATA = $2; 
    if(NR > 6) { 
        for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
            if( $i!= NODATA ) { 
                printf( "%f %f %f\n", LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE + CELLSIZE / 2, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) *    CELLSIZE - CELLSIZE / 2, $i ) 
            } 
        } 
  } 
}
```

Save that as `foo.awk`, make it executable, and run it on your file:

```
./foo.awk file
```